# UIControls Displaying Outside the Boundary of Parent Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've noticed that when controls are the children of other controls and lie partially outside the boundary of the parent control, the part of the control outside the boundary of the parent control can still be seen.

For example, I've placed an Image inside a Grid and partially outside the Grid's boundary, and yet the Image still displays completely.

How can I limit the amount of child controls to be displays to that within the bondary of parent controls?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you please show the xaml and snapshot of where image gone out of grid boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop WPF from displaying the image outside the bounds of your grid you can set [ClipToBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx)="True" on the grid.

Comment: Thanks heap for that! That's the solution.